# Result of Java split() is varies when working with string of numbers

Tags: java, split

Why does Java String.split() generate different results when working with string defined in code versus string read from a file when numbers are involved?  Specifically I have a file called "test.txt" that contains chars and numbers separated by spaces:

```
G H 5 4
```

The split method does not split on spaces as expected.  But if a string variable is created within code with same chars and numbers separated by spaces then the result of split() is four individual strings, one for char and number.  The code below demonstrates this difference:

```
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileReader;
   import java.io.BufferedReader;

   public class SplitNumber {

     //Read first line of text file
     public static void main(String[] args) {
       try {
         File file = new File("test.txt");
         FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
         BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fr);

         String firstLine;
         if ((firstLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
           String[] firstLineNumbers = firstLine.split("\\s+");
           System.out.println("First line array length: " + firstLineNumbers.length);

           for (int i=0; i<firstLineNumbers.length; i++) {
             System.out.println(firstLineNumbers[i]);
           }
         }
         bufferedReader.close();

         String numberString = "G H 5 4";
         String[] numbers = numberString.split("\\s+");
         System.out.println("Numbers array length: " + numbers.length);

         for (int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
           System.out.println(numbers[i]);
         }
       } catch(Exception exception) {
         System.out.println("IOException occured");
         exception.printStackTrace();
       }
     }
   }
```

The result is:

```
First line array length: 3
G
H
5 4
Numbers array length: 4
G
H
5
4
```

Why do the numbers from the file not get parsed the same as the same string defined within code?

Comment: What are the contents of the file?

Comment: it would seem that the last space in the file is not a space

Comment: find a hex editor and check the actual content in the file.  `\s` only matches ` \t\n\x0B\f\r` but there are some other "seems-to-be-whitespace" characters

Comment: BTW, a well formatted question - makes a nice change

Comment: Just a thought, you may try `split("[\\s\\h]+")` or even `split("[\\s\\h\\v]+")`. Seems it would include more whitespace-like characters. See the docs for more.

Answer (score 1):

Based on feedback I changed the regex to `split("[\\s\\h]+")` which resolved the issue; the numbers for the file were properly split which clearly indicated that I had a different whitespace-like character in the text file that I was using.  I then replaced the contents of the file (using notepad) and reverted back to `split("\\s+")` and found that it worked correctly this time.  So at some point I must have introduced different white-space like characters in the file (maybe a copy/paste issue).  In the end the take away is I should use `split("[\\s\\h]+")` when reading from a file where I want to split on spaces as it will cover more scenarios that may not be immediately obvious.

Thanks to all for helping me find the root cause of my issue.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your conclusion. It could be helpful to others.

Comment: I have edited the answer to address the invalid escaping of backslashes in regex.